# Cycles render is hiding some lights

Tags: rendering

I'm baffled about this issue I've recetly been having. So I have made a bunch of rooms in blender and all of them have a really big plane set up over them, with tiles, and some of those tiles emitting light. However when I render it in cycles, and this only happens in cycles render, not in viewport shading, as that is fine for some reasons, but when I render, all my rooms are completely dark, like the lights are'nt one except these four lights, I have no clue why..

So here's it in the viewport[image]

and here it is in the actual render, I really don't understand why all but those four lights inside the room with the wood flooring are only on...
[image]

Here's a top down view. [image]

And a ss of the material for the light, [image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have overlapping faces? (Z fighting)

Comment: How would I remove that?

Comment: AHAH IT WAS THAT, THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Answer (score 1):

you have overlapping faces, it's called *Z fighting* and it makes materials go black in Cycles, you need to switch to *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.